# Writing a single javascript line that defines a function and also returns a value based on the function result

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a single string of Javascript code that both defines a helper function, and uses it to return the value from that code (an object to be exact)
Still, I want the return value to just be the object, not the function definition, i.e. I want it to just execute the function. 
I don't care if as a side effect the function will also be defined in a global scope or similar.

For example I've tried the following:

```js
var a = (function xyz() {return 10; }, { "b": xyz() })
```

This returns: 
VM209:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: xyz is not defined(…)

If I use ";" instead I get the following:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

I'm trying it on a Chrome console. If that matters, please let me know.

Comment: var a = {b: (() => 10)()}

Comment: Thanks @Gerrit0, what if I'd like to use this function definition in multiple places in my object?

Comment: Then you would be best off by defining the function first, and then call it when you instantiate a. So, var xyz = () => 10; var a = {b: xyz()}

Comment: @Gerrit0, unfortunately that's not an option in my case. I want this as a single block that when evaluated will return the object, but that will be "self sufficient", including all of its dependent function(s). I need the string to be able to return the right value when used as such: "var a = <string>"

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense "a single sting" was confusing. Maybe something like this? `var a = (function() { var xyz = () => 10; return {a: xyz()}}())`

Answer (score 0):

From your description it sounds like you want it to return an object:

```
{
   "b":10
}
```

in which case what you want to do is:

```
var a = (function xyz() {return {"b":10};})()
```

If what you just want to do is have `a` be the return value, then what you want is:

```
var a = (function xyz() {return 10;})()
```

Either way, the syntax is the same, the return value just changes. You have to invoke the function at the end of its declaration using `()`

Comment: Your first assumption was correct, I'm looking to get { "b":10} back, but I want readability in the code block, such that I separate the function logic, from the usage in the object value. For instance, a date diff utility function that I can use from multiple locations in the object.